# Show database items in listview

Tags: android, listview

My code at the moment is working and displaying one item from the database,but after looking online, I put my data in an adapter, but it only displays the first item from the database. What should I change in order for it to display all the items of the database?

MarksActivity.java

```
 private void getData() {
            String nume = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
            if (nume.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(this, "Numele tau", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                return;
            }
            loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Te rugam asteapta","Fetching...",false,false);

            String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

            StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    loading.dismiss();
                    showJSON(response);
                }
            },
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            Toast.makeText(MarksActivity.this, error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    });

            RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
            requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
        }

        private void showJSON(String response){

            String nota="";
            String materie="";
            String profesor = "";
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<result.length();i++)
                    Log.v("Result--",""+result.getString(i));
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
                nota = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
                materie = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
                profesor = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }



            String[] status = {"Nota:\t"+nota+"\nMaterie:\t" +materie+ "\nProfesor:\t"+ profesor};

            textViewResult.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MarksActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The last value only must have shown. I suggest you to initialize​ the String[] Status above loop and add each item in status inside the loop. You will get result!

Create a model class as DemoObject:

```
public class DemoObject {
    private String nota;

    public String getNota() {
        return nota;
    }

    public void setNota(String nota) {
        this.nota = nota; 
    }
}
```

Now,

```
private void showJSON(String response){
            DemoObject demoObject = new DemoObject();
            List<DemoObject> list = new ArrayList();
            try {
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
                for(i=0;i<result.length();i++)
                    Log.v("Result--",""+result.getString(i));
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(0);
                demoObject.setNota(collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME));
                list.add(demoObject);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Finally,

```
textViewResult.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MarksActivity.this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list));
```

Comment: How exactly can I add each inside the loop?

Comment: If I initialize the String[] Status above the loop it won't work

Comment: Edited the post!

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the `showJson` method
you need to initialize the string array at the beginning and add items there

```
private void showJSON(String response){

        List<String> status = new ArrayList<String>(); // since you don't know exactly how many elements are there in the json array
        String nota="";
        String materie="";
        String profesor = "";
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
            for(i=0;i<result.length();i++) {
                Log.v("Result--",""+result.getString(i));
                JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
                nota = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
                materie = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
                profesor = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
                status.add("Nota:\t"+nota+"\nMaterie:\t" +materie+ "\nProfesor:\t"+ profesor);
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


        textViewResult.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MarksActivity.this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status));
    }
```

Comment: Do I need to declare the list and the ArrayList in my xml?

Comment: no they are provided in the `java.util` package, so just add `import java.util.List; import java.util.ArrayList;` at the beginning of the file

Comment: Still only displays the first item from the DB

Comment: can you post the log please

Comment: Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe, this is the only error I get

Comment: at the beginning of the method try logging the response string

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: at the beginning of showJSON method write `Log.i("Response", response);`

Comment: It still only displays the first item, but now I get this android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity login.evidenta.evidentastudentilor.activity.MarksActivity has leaked window DecorView@eeea13e[Te rugam asteapta] that was originally added here          loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Te rugam asteapta","Fetching...",false,false); public void onClick(View v)  This is where it says that I have the errors

Comment: in that case then the error is not in android code, but in the route you used to get the json object (the error is probably in the url)

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, your showJSON method should be like below:

```
private void showJSON(String response){

    String nota="";
    String materie="";
    String profesor = "";
    String[] status = null; 
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        status = new String[result.length()];

        for(i=0;i<result.length();i++) {
            Log.v("Result--",""+result.getString(i));

            JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
            nota = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
            materie = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
            profesor = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);

            status[i] = "Nota:\t"+nota+"\nMaterie:\t" +materie+ "\nProfesor:\t"+ profesor;       
        }


    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MarksActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, status);
    textViewResult.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Comment: Still only displays the first item

Comment: This edited answer should work. I think textViewResult is listview..and other define ArrayAdapter<String> adapter as above and declare everytime. Debug and check that you are getting more entries in result JSONArray. Hope this will help u..

Comment: Yes, the textViewResult is a listview, but it still only displays the first item

Answer (score 0):

```
private void getData() {
        String nume = editTextId.getText().toString().trim();
        if (nume.equals("")) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Numele tau", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return;
        }
        loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Te rugam asteapta","Fetching...",false,false);

        String url = Config.DATA_URL+editTextId.getText().toString().trim();

        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                loading.dismiss();
                showJSON(response);
            }
        },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        Toast.makeText(MarksActivity.this, error.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                });

        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }



    private void showJSON(String response){

    List<String> status = new ArrayList<String>(); // since you don't know exactly how many elements are there in the json array
    String nota="";
    String materie="";
    String profesor = "";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.JSON_ARRAY);
        for(i=0;i<result.length();i++) {
            Log.v("Result--",""+result.getString(i));
        JSONObject collegeData = result.getJSONObject(i);
        nota = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_NAME);
        materie = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_ADDRESS);
        profesor = collegeData.getString(Config.KEY_VC);
        status.add("Nota:\t"+nota+"\nMaterie:\t" +materie+ "\nProfesor:\t"+ profesor);
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }


    textViewResult.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(MarksActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, status));
}
```